# How to add a new column in data frame using calculation in R?

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column with calculation. In the below data frame,

```
Env<- c("High_inoc","High_NO_inoc","Low_inoc", "Low_NO_inoc")
CV1<- c(30,150,20,100)
CV2<- c(74,99,49,73)
CV3<- c(78,106,56,69)
CV4<- c(86,92,66,70)
CV5<- c(74,98,57,79)

Data<-data.frame(Env,CV1,CV2,CV3,CV4,CV5)

Data$Mean <- rowMeans(Data %>% select(-Env))
Data <- rbind(Data, c("Mean", colMeans(Data %>% select(-Env))))
```

[image]

I'd like to add a new column names 'Env_index' with calculation {each value of 'mean' column - overall mean (**76.3**) such as 68.4 - **76.3** , 109- **76.3** ,... 78.2 - **76.3**

So, I did like this and obtained what I want.

```
Data$Env_index <- c(68.4-76.3,109-76.3,49.6-76.3,78.2-76.3, 76.3-76.3)
```

[image]

But, I want to directly calculate using code, so if I code like this,

```
Data$Env_index <- with (data, data$Mean - 76.3)
```

It generates error. Could you let me know how to calculate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the calculation dynamic which will work on any data you can do :

```
Data$Mean <- as.numeric(Data$Mean)
Data$Env_index <- Data$Mean - Data$Mean[nrow(Data)]
Data

#           Env CV1   CV2   CV3  CV4 CV5  Mean Env_index
#1    High_inoc  30    74    78   86  74  68.4      -7.9
#2 High_NO_inoc 150    99   106   92  98 109.0      32.7
#3     Low_inoc  20    49    56   66  57  49.6     -26.7
#4  Low_NO_inoc 100    73    69   70  79  78.2       1.9
#5         Mean  75 73.75 77.25 78.5  77  76.3       0.0
```

`Data$Mean[nrow(Data)]` will select last value of `Data$Mean`.